# Button não muda setas de expansão

Tags: php, javascript, html

Em meu projeto, possuo alguns "steps" a ser seguidos e para avançar os steps, eu coloquei buttons de "Continue" no final de cada steps, eles expandem o próximo collapse e fecham o anterior, porém, eu coloquei também setas que trocam de imagem (direita fechado, para baixo aberto) quando se clicam nelas ou no título e quando eu clico no botão para avançar, elas não mudam, assim ficando algumas para baixo e outras para a direita.

Eu gostaria que elas acompanhassem o collapse, quando fechado, elas voltassem para a direita e quando abertas, elas virassem para baixo, isso só acontece caso eu clique nelas ou no título, no botão não.

Código do botão:

```
<div class="form-group row"><br/>
     <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="next(2)">
         Continue <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
     </button>
</div>
```

Código JS das setas que trocam:

```
$('h1.change').click(function (){
    var img1 = 'assets/img/arrow_right.png';
    var img2 = 'assets/img/arrow_down.png';
    var index = $(this).attr('index');
    var element = $('img[index='+index+']');
    if(element.attr('src') === img1){
        element.attr('src',img2);
    }else if(element.attr('src') === img2){
        element.attr('src',img1);

    }
});
```

Código dos collapses:

```
<h1 index="1" class="collapsed change" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" 
aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" ng-click="alert_step2()">
    <img index="1" class="change img-change" src="assets/img/arrow_right.png" style="width: 20px; height: 25px">
    Step 2 - Acknowledge Your Strengths (highest scores)
</h1>
```

Não tenho experiência com javascript e estou aprendendo, essas setas estão me dando muito trabalho.

Mudanças do collapse:

```
    if(step == 1)

{

    $('#collapseOne').collapse('hide');     

    $('#collapseTwo').collapse('show');

    $(".img-change").attr("src", "assets/img/arrow_right.png");

    $("[data-toggle=collapse]").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("aria-expanded", "false").addClass("collapsed");
    $($(this).attr("href")).removeClass("show");
    });

}
```

Final do código js

```
    else if(step == 11)

{

    $('#collapseTen').collapse('hide');     

    $('#collapseEleven').collapse('show');

    $(".img-change").attr("src", "assets/img/arrow_right.png");

}

   $('h1.change:eq('+(step-1)+')').trigger("click", step);


}
</script>

</script>

<script>

$('h1.change').click(function (e, step){
var img1 = 'assets/img/arrow_right.png';
var img2 = 'assets/img/arrow_down.png';

if(step) $(".img-change").attr("src", img1);

var index = $(this).attr('index');
var element = $('img[index='+index+']', this);
if(element.attr('src') === img1){
    element.attr('src',img2);
}else if(element.attr('src') === img2){
    element.attr('src',img1);

}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Tente colocando na função `next()` um código para mudar as imagens: `$(".img-change").attr("src", "assets/img/arrow_right.png");`

Comment: @sam resolveu, mas apareceu outro problema, pode me ajudar? Agora ela fecha, porém, não abre a próxima seta pro próximo collapse. Tipo, ao clicar no botão, ela abre o próximo collapse e fecha o atual, o atual troca com o código que você passou, porém o próximo não troca e mostra que ta aberto, o ícone continua fechado enquanto ele está aberto. Poderia me ajudar? Qualquer coisa, posta a resposta fora de um comentário pra eu te marcar como respondido! Aliás, obrigado!

Comment: Remova todo o código que sugeri. Troque a linha `var element = $('img[index='+index+']');` por `var element = $('img[index='+index+']', this);`

Comment: Sem sucesso ainda, as setas continuam fechadas a cada troca de collapse

Comment: Vc só tem 2 collapses? O botão é sempre onclick="next(2)"?

Comment: Não, tenho 12 collapses, o botão é sempre next(1), next(2), next(3), e por aí vai.

Comment: Ok, esse botões vão dentro dos collapses, cada qual?

Comment: Sim, cada um está dentro de um collapse, quer que eu poste o código de um dos collapses?

Comment: Veja se é mais ou menos isso: https://jsfiddle.net/hc9fd540/

Comment: É exatamente isso que eu quero

Answer (score 0):

Você pode simplificar o código criando um evento para os `h1` e para os botões e ir alterando os collapses conforme os cliques. Crie um objeto com as URL's das imagens que fica mais fácil de trabalhar também. Ao abrir um painel, irá fechar os que estiverem abertos e alterar as setas. Ao clicar no botão "Continuar" irá abrir o próximo painel e alterar as setas conforme for fechado e aberto o painel.

Não é necessário usar esses atributos `index` que está usando para identificar os elementos. Também não precisa usar a função `next()` com if's repetitivos que torna a manutenção bem mais complicada. Veja:

```js
$('h1.change').click(function (e, step){
   var imgs = {
    img1: 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/32pxmania/misc_18.png',
    img2: 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/woothemesiconset/32/blue_arrow_down.png'
   }
    
   var seta = $("img", this).attr("src");
   var c = $(".collapse.show");
   c.closest(".card").find("h1.change img").attr("src", imgs.img1);
   c.collapse('hide');
   
   if(!step && seta == imgs.img1){
      step = 2;
   }else if(!step && seta != imgs.img1){
      step = 1;
   }

   $("img", this).attr("src", imgs['img'+step]);

});

$(".card button.btn.btn-primary").click(function(){
   var t = $(this).closest(".card");
   t.find("h1.change").trigger("click", 1);
   t.next(".card").find("h1.change").trigger("click", 2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card">
   <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
         <h1 index="1" class="collapsed change" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" ng-click="alert_step2()"> <img index="1" class="change img-change" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/32pxmania/misc_18.png" style="width: 20px; height: 25px">Step 2 - Acknowledge Your Strengths (highest scores)</h1>
      </h5>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo"  ng-click="alert_step2()">
      <div class="card-block">
         <h4>Whatever you focus on expands. Focusing on your strengths supports your remembrance of being capable, victorious and powerful. It is your strengths that will provide the ability and confidence to succeed in creating what you want in your life and happiness, financial freedom, radiant health, peace of mind. You will draw upon these strengths and apply them to the areas of your life that need support. </h4>
         <div align="center" class="col-md-12" id="plotStep2"></div>
         <div align="center">
            <div class="form-group row">
               <div class="form-group row">              <br/>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary"> Continue <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
               </div> 
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
   <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
         <h1 index="3" class="collapsed change" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo" ng-click="alert_step2()"> <img index="3" class="change img-change" src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/32pxmania/misc_18.png" style="width: 20px; height: 25px">Step 3 - Acknowledge Your Strengths (highest scores)</h1>
      </h5>
   </div>
   <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo"  ng-click="alert_step2()">
      <div class="card-block">
         <h4>Whatever you focus on expands. Focusing on your strengths supports your remembrance of being capable, victorious and powerful. It is your strengths that will provide the ability and confidence to succeed in creating what you want in your life and happiness, financial freedom, radiant health, peace of mind. You will draw upon these strengths and apply them to the areas of your life that need support. </h4>
         <div align="center" class="col-md-12" id="plotStep2"></div>
         <div align="center">
            <div class="form-group row">
               <div class="form-group row">              <br/>
                  <button class="btn btn-primary"> Continue <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
               </div> 
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Eu coloquei e não funcionou amigo, olha o exemplo, eu coloquei no post principal

Comment: Eu lendo seu comentário de novo, não sei se entendeu... O collapse fecha normal quando aperto o botão "Continue" o problema é que as setas não voltam para a posição fechada. Fechado = seta direita -- Aberto = seta para baixo. Quando aperto o button, ela continua mostrando a seta para baixo, mesmo com o collapse fechado

Comment: Ainda não obtive sucesso, acho que fiz da maneira como falou, o $('h1.change:eq('+(step-1)+')').trigger("click", step); ficou no fim da function next(step), como você colocou no código e eu até copiei o seu JS, mudando o url das setas, claro, e mesmo assim não funcionou

Comment: a seta seguinte ainda não abre para baixo, só o collapse

Comment: sim, está assim:     var element = $('img[index='+index+']', this);

Comment: O código js que você postou, antes da function next, eu copiei e colei, só trocando as url de seta só, não mudei nada que você colocou

Comment: Coloquei o final do código do function next, logo após inicio outra tag script e inicio o código js da troca, veja se está tudo certo

Comment: qual .each? Eu não achei

Comment: Ah mas ele nem tá no meu código também

Comment: as 3 linhas de código do  $("[role=tabpanel]").collapse('hide');, vão ao final da function next, em cada function? Eu coloquei as 3 no final da function, mantendo tudo como estava e o botão não funcionava. Daí eu substituí todos os if e else if colocando somente o código que estava e quando aperto o botão, ele fecha o atual expande todos os outros de uma só vez e ainda não troca a imagem da seta,

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eup8b61L/2/
Todos os collapses que possuo estão aí e o código javascript antes das suas mudanças, eu voltei ao que tava antes que funcionava os collapses e a foto trocava mas após apertar o botão não trocava mais. Se precisar de alguma informação, pode pedir! Obrigado mesmo pela ajuda!

Comment: Veja agora. Basta apenas copiar o JS. Como eu disse na resposta, não é necessário usar os atributos index e a função next().

Comment: Eu troquei todo o código JS, e inclusive usei como exemplo o seu h1, mudando apenas as informações para funcionar em cada step, e não obtive sucesso ainda, não entendo porque no exemplo que roda aqui no stack, funciona, e no meu não, não sei onde estou fazendo errado